# How to calculate MLM User Income points in php

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child, recursive-query

I'm trying to Calculate Income Points for MLM network Users (i.e).,

I'm having five types of kits such as Rs.0/-, Rs.1000/-, Rs.2000/-, Rs.4000/-, Rs.10000/- .
Once the kit is purchased a unique pin and user id will generate for each individual kit like

```
If 2 number of 2000/- kit purchased means userid and pin will be

    2000100 539fdda37c435 and
    2000101 5395b0d8b66d1 .....
```

Then Based on new user sponsor id(Sponsor id will be old user), registration will be proceed with Group left and right.

Now what's my problem is While calculating income point of a user how can i take their children user from top to bottom. I'd strucked in MYSQL Query.

For Example.,
[image: example tree view]

now how can i get each node's value for a parent node(1) to root node(12) from this dynamic tree in php ??
I struck in this loop concept.,

Thanks IN Advance.,

Comment: Actually it depends on the table architecture you have. Show your table to help u.

Answer (score -1):

database architecture

```
id  par lev lef rgt status  wallet userstatus
1   1   1   2   3    1        0       0
2   2   2   4   5    1        0       0
6   3   2   6   7    1        0       0
8   4   3   8   9    1        0       0
9   5   3   10  11   1        0       0
10  6   3   12  13   1        0       0
11  7   3   0   0    1        0       0
```

Comment: how does this in any way answer the question?

Comment: I'm trying to get how many pairs under one leg so every time when i'm registering a new leg i'm saving the level he is and his parent node id. So is there any possible way to find how many pair under say "1" node, the result is 5 pairs as per that tree image.